# How to work out following problem -> "sum of the multiples of 6 less than 100"

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm not sure how to approach this without just brute forcing it, which would be doable for numbers lower than 100 but obviously not great and certainly not for 2000 or something.

I know that the multiples of 6 less than a hundred are going to be multiples of 3 and 2, I know that there are 33 multiples of 3 less than 100, but I'm not sure how to determine which of these are divisible by 2 and 3 without making a table and going through them all.

3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30

In the first 10 set of 3s there are 5 sets of 6, so I'm guessing this applies for the next two (30 to 60 and 60 to 90). So at 90 there should be 15 multiples of 6. Then 96 is a multiple, so that's 16.

Of course 16 * 6 = 96, but I'm going through series at the moment and I'm trying think of a 'better way' than times tables, even though for this problem that might have been the fastest.

the full question is :

$$\text{Rewrite the following sums using } \Sigma \text{ notation}$$

$$\text{d. The multiples of 6 less than 100}$$
thank you.

Comment: Write this as an arithmetic sequence: $6,12,18,...,96$ and then make use of the sum of an arithmetic sequence formula. Use the one that makes use of the fact that you know both the first and last terms of the seqence.

Comment: thanks for that @Mufasa , much needed nudge... So wrote it out as you said, then worked out n terms with $$96 = 6+(n-1)6$$, then used the number of terms in the formula $$\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)6)$$, and got the answer 816. Not sure how to 'close' this question now, but that's all good (should I delete it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read at the end that it is asking you to write the sum in $\Sigma$ notation.

You want to sum this sequence: $6+12+18+...+96$

This can be written as: $(1\times6)+(2\times6)+(3\times6)+...+(16\times6)$

Can you now write this sum using $\Sigma$ notation?

Comment: oh yeh sos, I'm not sure of the LaTeX for this ;) ~~that went through by mistake I'm editing this~~ So with sigma it would be the sigma sign with r = 1 underneath and 16 above it, then the 'condition' (I'm not sure what the parts are called) would be (6r)

Comment: Yes, i.e. $\sum_{r=1}^{16}6r$